# Why the projection operator $P_M$ can be written as $x \bigotimes x$?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Recall the projection theorem for Hilbert spaces. If $M$ is a closed subspace of a Hilbert space $H$, it stated that for each $x \in H$, there was a unique element in $M$ that minimized the norm difference $||x-y||$ over all $y \in M$. We denote this minimizing element by $P_M x$. When viewed as a function on $H$, $P_M$ is referred to as the projection operator for the subspace $M$.

If the subspace of $M$ of $H$ has dimension one and is spanned by $x$ with $||x||=1$, then $P_M$ can be written as $x \otimes x$ where

$$(x \otimes x)y= \langle y,x \rangle x$$

for any $y \in H$. This can be established with the following theorem upon observing $\langle y,x \rangle =  \langle (x \otimes x)y,x \rangle  ,y \in H$.

The theorem is that let $M$ is a closed linear subspace of a Hilbert space $H$. For any element $x \in H$, there exists a unique element of $M$ that minimizes $||x-y||$ over $y \in M$. The minimizer $\hat x$ is uniquely determined by the condition

$$\langle \hat x, y \rangle =\langle  x, y \rangle$$ for all $y \in M$.

**My question:** I don't understand why $P_M$ can be written as $x \bigotimes x$ where

$$(x \otimes x)y= \langle y,x \rangle x$$. And also it mentions that "If the subspace of $M$ of $H$ has dimension one and is spanned by $x$ with $||x||=1$", where do we use this assumption?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also deal with it as follows.

Let $M=\left\{k x\in H\mid k\in\mathbb{C}\right\}.$ If $h\in H,$ then $h=kx+y,$ (written uniquely) where $k\in\mathbb{C}$ and $y\in M^{\perp}.$ Thus $P_{M}(h)=kx$ and $$k=k\,\langle{x,x\rangle}=\langle{P_{M}(h),x\rangle}.$$

Finally, $P_{M}(h)=\langle{P_{M}(h),x\rangle}x=\langle{h,x\rangle}x\,\,$ since $\langle{y,x\rangle}=0.$

Comment: How to think $x \otimes x$ here?

Comment: In general, if $H$ is a Hilbert space and $x,\,y\in H$ you can define the so-called rank-1 operator $x\otimes y$ (or $x\otimes y^*$) by $$(x\otimes y)(h)=\langle{h,y\rangle}x,\,\,h\in H.$$

Comment: so here the $\otimes$ operator is not the usual outer productor?

Answer (score 0):

One potential source of confusion is that the letters $x$ and $y$ are being used in very different ways across these statements and it can be difficult to keep the differences straight.  As one example:

- In "The minimizer $\hat{x}$ is uniquely determined by the condition [involving $x$, $\hat{x}$, and $y$] for all $y \in M$" the letter $x$ is implicitly an arbitrary element of $H$ (it is fixed for purposes of discussing the issue of projection, but is otherwise arbitrary in $H$), while $y$ is an arbitrary element of $M$.
- In "If the subspace $M$ of $H$ has dimension one and is spanned by $x$ with $\|x\| = 1$ then $P_M$ can be writtten $x \otimes x$ where $(x \otimes x) y = \langle y, x \rangle x$ for any $y$ in $H$" the letter $x$ is now an element of $M$ of norm $1$ (i.e., $x$ no longer an arbitrary element of $H$, and not even an arbitrary element of $M$ but an element of $M$ with a particular norm), and the letter $y$ is now an arbitrary element of $H$ (i.e., $y$ is no longer an arbitrary element of $M$ or even an element of $M$ at all).

While it is not uncommon for textbooks and other sources to run through very different uses of the same symbols in situations where a skilled reader will recognize that the symbols are just "dummy variables" (i.e., where as long as the symbols are properly quantified, there is no ambiguity in their mathematical meaning), this use of symbols is sub-optimal from the point of view of understanding or explaining things.

Let's fix the discussion as follows.  We have a Hilbert space $H$ and a subspace $M$ of $H$.  We will let $x$ denote an arbitrary element of $H$ fixed for purposes of discussing its orthogonal projection onto $M$.  We will denote the orthogonal projection of $x$ onto $M$ by $\hat{x}$.  We will use the letter $y$ and variants to denote elements of $M$.

When $M$ is one-dimensional, the condition that $\langle \hat{x}, y \rangle = \langle x, y \rangle$ hold for all $y \in M$, which should generally be thought of as a *family* of conditions (one condition for each element of $M$, or at least one condition for each element of a spanning set in $M$), can be replaced with a single condition: that this equality hold for a single nonzero element $y$ of $M$ (indeed, any nonzero element $y$ of $M$ that you like).

More explicitly, if $M$ is one dimensional and $y_1$ is a nonzero element of $M$, then $M = \{ty_1: \text{$t$ a scalar}\}$, so that the condition $\langle \hat{x}, y \rangle = \langle x, y \rangle$ will hold for all $y \in M$ if and only if the condition $\langle \hat{x}, t y_1 \rangle = \langle x, t y_1 \rangle$ holds for all scalars $t$, which (because the scalar $t$ can be pulled out of both inner products and canceled whenever it is nonzero) will hold if any only if the (single!) condition $\langle \hat{x}, y_1 \rangle = \langle x, y_1 \rangle$ holds.  Because the $\hat{x}$ we are seeking to identify by this equation is also in $M$ (still assumed one-dimensional), $\hat{x}$ is also a multiple of $y_1$.  Writing $\hat{x} = \hat{t} y_1$ and solving the equation $\langle \hat{x}, y_1 \rangle = \langle x, y_1 \rangle$ for the unknown scalar $\hat{t}$, we see that $\hat{t}$ is determined by $\langle \hat{t} y_1, y_1 \rangle = \langle x, y_1 \rangle$, so that $\hat{t} = \frac{\langle x, y_1 \rangle}{\langle y_1, y_1 \rangle}$.  It follows that $\hat{x} = \hat{t} y_1$ is given by the formula $\hat{x} = \frac{\langle x, y_1 \rangle}{\langle y_1, y_1 \rangle} y_1$.  If we had happened to choose our nonzero spanning element $y_1$ of $M$ to have norm $1$, the denominator $\langle y_1, y_1 \rangle$ of the fraction just written would be $1$ and the formula would read
$$
\hat{x} = \langle x, y_1 \rangle y_1.
$$
The right hand side of the above appears to be literally your definition of the operator "$y_1 \otimes y_1$" applied to $x$.  So if we also chose to write $P_M(x)$ instead of $\hat{x}$ we would deduce
$P_M(x) = (y_1 \otimes y_1)(x)$ or indeed $P_M = y_1 \otimes y_1$ if we are comfortable with writing equalities of operators on $H$.

So in a notation that is slightly more consistent with the above discussion, we might summarize all this by saying "If the subspace $M$ of $H$ has dimension one and is spanned by $y_1$ with $\|y_1\| = 1$, then $P_M = y_1 \otimes y_1$."

This fact generalizes in way that lets one "see" how the one-dimensional case relates to higher dimensional cases.  When $M$ is $n$-dimensional (where $n$ is assumed finite but no longer assumed to be $1$), the condition that $\langle \hat{x}, y \rangle = \langle x, y \rangle$ hold for all $y \in M$ is equivalent to a finite list of $n$ conditions, namely, that $\langle \hat{x}, y_k \rangle = \langle x, y_k \rangle$ hold for all $1 \leq k \leq n$, where $y_1, \dots, y_n$ is a basis of $M$.  Should you decide to choose $y_1, \dots, y_n$ to be an *orthonormal* basis for $M$, and should you decide to see how $\hat{x} = \sum_{k=1}^n \hat{t}_k y_k$ looks in terms of this orthonormal basis, algebra similar to the $n = 1$ case allows you conclude that $\hat{x} = \sum_{k=1}^n \langle x, y_k \rangle y_k$, so that more generally we can deduce $
P_M = \sum_{k=1}^n y_k \otimes y_k$, which we might summarize by saying that "if the subspace $M$ of $H$ has dimension $n$ and is spanned by the orthonormal vectors $y_1, \dots, y_n$, then $P_M = \sum_{k=1}^n y_k \otimes y_k$."  [Note that without the background understanding of what this operator sum represents, it might not be clear why it should be independent of the choice of $y_1, \dots, y_n$.  Note that each term $y_k \otimes y_k$ and indeed any partial sum of the full sum will generally depend on the choice of basis.]

This statement can be generalized to more general $M$, if mild care is taken to define the ingredients (e.g. infinite orthonormal sets of vectors, infinite "spans," and infinite operator sums).